# Is there any practical usage of Doubly Linked List, Queues and Stacks?

Tags: data-structures

I've been coding for quite sometime now. And my work pertains to solving real-world business scenarios. However, I have not really come across any practical usage of some of the data structures like the Linked List, Queues and Stacks etc.

Not even at the business framework level. Of course, there is the ubiquitous HashTable, ArrayList and of late the List...but is there any practical usage of some of the other basic data structures?

It would be great if someone gave a real-world solution where a Doubly Linked List "performs" better than the obvious easily usable counterpart.

Comment: Going by previous set of answers,  effectively this means these data structures are just the foundations.... in a sense like Assembly Language compared to C#... :) .

Comment: Generally those more specialized data structures go along with particular algorithms that fit well with them. In business logic your typical algorithms are "go through every entry in this list in order" (List works great) or "fetch an item, read/modify it, put it back" (HashTable works great). Linked lists are used extensively in functional programming, although they have their uses in imperative languages as well.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it’s possible to get by with only a `Map` (aka `HashTable`) and a `List`. A `Queue` is only a glorified `List` but if you use a `Queue` everywhere you really need a queue then your code gets a lot more readable because nobody has to guess what you are using that `List` for.

And then there are algorithms that work a lot better when the underlying data structure is not a plain `List` but a `DoublyLinkedList` due to the way they have to navigate the list. The same is valid for all other data structures: there’s always a use for them. :)

Comment: By "work a lot better"...you mean more efficiently than the corresponding List counterpart? Please elucidate

Comment: Imaging the (theoretically infinite) tape of a turing machine. You might implement it as a `List`; that would enable you to go right without any problems but going left would require you to start at the beginning and iterate through the slots until you’re at the one to the left of the one you started with. When using a `DoublyLinkedList` moving left is just as simple as moving right.

Comment: (And I had to look up “elucidate”—I guessed it right, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Stacks can be used for pairing (parseing) such as matching open brackets to closing brackets.

Queues can be used for messaging, or activity processing.

Linked list, or double linked lists can be used for circular navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these algorithms are usually at a lower level than your usual "business" application. For example indices on the database is a variation of a multiply linked list. Implementation of function calling mechanism(or a parse tree) is a stack. Queues and FIFOs are used for servicing network request etc.

These are just examples of collection structures that are optimized for speed in various scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

LIFO-Stack and FIFO-Queue are reasonably abstract (behavioral spec-level) data structures, so **of course** there are plenty of practical uses for them. For example, LIFO-Stack is a great way to help remove recursion (stack up the current state and loop, instead of making a recursive call); FIFO-Queue helps "buffer up" and "peel away" work nuggets in a coroutine arrangement; etc, etc.

Doubly-linked-List is more of an implementation issue than a behavioral spec-level one, mostly... can be a good way to implement a FIFO-Queue, for example. If you need a sequence with fast splicing and removal give a pointer to one sequence iten, you'll find plenty of other real-world uses, too.

Answer (score 1):

I use queues, linked lists etc. in business solutions all the time.

Except they are implemented by Oracle, IBM, JMS etc.

These constructs are generally at a much lower level of abstaction than you would want while implementing a business solution. Where a business problem would benifit from
such low level constructs (e.g. delivery route planning, production line scheduling etc.) there is usually a package available to do it or you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use them very often, but they do come up.  For example, I'm using a queue in a current project to process asynchronous character equipment changes that must happen in the order the user makes them.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is useful if you have a subset of "selected" items out of a larger set of items, where you must perform one type of operation on a "selected" item and a default operation or no operation at all on a normal item and the set of "selected" items can change at will (possibly due to user input).  Because linked list removal can be done nearly instantaneously (vs. the traversal time it would take for an array search), if the subsets are large enough then it's faster to maintain a linked list than to either maintain an array or regenerate the whole subset by scanning through the whole larger set every time you need the subset.

With a hash table or binary tree, you could search for a single "selected" item, but you couldn't search for all "selected" items without checking every item (or having a separate dictionary for every permutation of selected items, which is obviously impractical).

A queue can be useful if you are in a scenario where you have a lot of requests coming in and you want to make sure to handle them fairly, in order.

I use stacks whenever I have a recursive algorithm, which usually means it's operating on some hierarchical data structure, and I want to print an error message if I run out of memory instead of simply letting the software crash if the program stack runs out of space.  Instead of calling the function recursively, I store its local variables in an object, run a loop, and maintain a stack of those objects.